# Get the wrong sort of an array (writing heap sort in Python)

Tags: python, sorting, heap

I have written the following heap sort code and I get the wrong output (not sorted) at times and I can't seem to find why...any help will be much appreciated! (WARNING: I am still learning Python that might be the problem)

```
def heap_sort(self, a):

    self.build_max_heap(a)
    n = len(a)-1
    i = len(a)-1

    for i in range(len(a)-1, 1):
        temp = a[0]
        a[0] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp
        a.heapsize = heapsize - 1
        self.max_heapify(a, 0)       #rebuild max heap at with new root



def max_heapify(self, a, i):

    left = (2*(i+1))-1      #left child of i
    right = 2*(i+1)             #right child of i
    largest = i

    if left < a.heapsize and a[left] > a[i]:
        largest = left

    if right < a.heapsize and a[right] > a[largest]:
        largest = right

    if largest != i:
        temp = a[largest]
        a[largest] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp
        self.max_heapify(a, largest)



def build_max_heap(self, a):

    heapsize = len(a)
    i = int(heapsize/2)-1

    for i in range(i, 0):
        self.max_heapify(a, i)
```

These are my tests:

```
#--Test for 0 in array--#
def zero_array(self):
    a = [12,0,232]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for duplicate in array--#
def duplicate_array(self):
    a = [12, 12, 7]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for all same values in array--#
def allsame_array(self):
    a = [1,1,1]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for negative values in array--#
def negative_array(self):
    a = [-23, -2, 123]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return
```

I get the following returned arrays (which are suppose to be sorted):

```
    [12, 0, 232]
    [12, 12, 7]
    [1, 1, 1]
    [-23, -2, 123]
```

Comment: Two side points: first, your `n = ` and `i =` lines in `heap_sort` don't do anything -- you never use `n` and you immediately clobber `i` in the loop.  Second, you can swap two entries in a list using something like `a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]` without needing a `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one issue right away:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, 1)
```

If you want to go down to 1 inclusive use:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! ... And for that I now love you... (knew it was some python syntax issue lol)